# How to turn windows forms app into native ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have written a windows form app in C#, but I want to turn it into native code for ASP.NET so I can build a webapp around it. However, I've never used ASP.NET and I'm not sure how to approach this. I've looked around and seen libraries such as VisualJS.Net, but it looks confusing and I'm not sure if I can seamlessly integrate it into my app without causing problems later on. Could someone lead me towards the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You might consider doing a ClickOne application. It's trivial to turn a Window Forms app into one of those, and no need to learn how to build a website. Depending on your needs, that might suffice.

Comment: another option is to "virtualize" access to the application...http://www.cybelesoft.com/thinfinity/virtualui/ .... those guys have a provided a unique way to access applications via a Web Browser...you could then modify the chrome/theme of your Windows Forms application so that it "looked" less like an "application"....though you do have to have a server/gateway, and pay client licences.....but for Enterprise sites....it's quite reasonable.....seems one feasible option compared to dropping 10s or 100s of £K on redeveloping as a "web"/ASP.NET app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I well understand, you would like to "transform" a Windows Forms app into a ASP.NET. The problem with this approach, is that those two technologies are like day and night. They don't have the same lifecycle at all. Windows applications are by definition stateful. This means that they keep their state in memory and they don't need to rebuild it often (maybe at the loading of a file). Web applications however are completely stateless. The server receives a request, processes it and returns web content (HTML, JSON and whatever is needed). If the server is again contacted with new information, the state must be rebuilt (with the help of cookies, sessions, etc).*

However, what you can do the ease those problems is the following. If you separate your concerns, you can more easily reuse your business logic and your data and just re-code the view of your application. This means that you must separate what belongs to a View technology (WinForms, ASP.NET) from the model itself. There are numerous patterns to support this : MVC, MVP, MVVM. Respecting GRASP patterns also helps.

With that in mind, you could have three solutions : One containing your common code, one containing the logic that belongs to WinForms and another one that contains your ASP.NET logic. It's easier said than done, but this should be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn an apple into an orange. Those two technologies are so different, that you will be better off rewriting the application from scratch, and taking advantage of all the goodies available in ASP.Net MVC 5.

Technically speaking one could devise some type of a converter, but it would potentially promote bad coding practices, something you should avoid.

Start learning MVC 5, you will be better off in the end.